# Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError on integration test with capybara-webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am trying to write an integration test using Capybara and capybara-webkit. I am stuck on trying to confirm an alert dialog. The documentation for capybara-webkit says to set `Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit` which I have done, but I don't see how this would affect Capybara::page.driver, which I think is supposed to respond to `accept_alert`:

```
def test_update_key
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
  visit account_path accounts(:pending_account)

  click_link "edit_account_key"
  page.accept_alert "Would you like to edit this account key?" do # error on this line
    click_button('OK')
  end
end
```

this code gives me the following error:

> Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError Exception: Capybara::Driver::Base#accept_modal

I am currently using rails (4.0.13), capybara (2.4.4), capybara-webkit (1.4.1)

Comment: Have you tried appending the `js: true` option to your test?

Comment: I'm using minitest, so I don't know if that option is supported - or where I would put it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what `Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit` is supposed to do, but it didn't do anything for me. I finally resolved the issue by putting `Capybara.current_driver = :webkit` in the top of my test.

However, webkit was still unable to accept the alert; I just changed the driver to Selenium for now, as that runs without issues. I had wanted to use webkit because it's headless, and reportedly faster, but I don't have a lot of tests written yet, so speed isn't an issue at this point. May have to revisit later.